# API or put the logic inside the app?

Tags: android, api, security, amazon-web-services

I'm busy building an app for android. When it's properly received by Android users I would like to expand to iOS.

But, before we get there, I first want to make the right choice. So my question, what to do?:

1. writing all the logic inside the app and use Cognito (https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/security/post/Tx3LP54JOGBE0AY/Building-an-App-using-Amazon-Cognito-and-an-OpenID-Connect-Identity-Provider) to access the data from DynamoDB
2. or let my app connect with my own API which handles the validation rules, which I then connect with DynamoDB database (don't know or API -> Cognito -> DynamoDB is a better solution, didn't really used it yet so...).

Now we all know about those issues where hackers built ways to bypass certain validation rules (as far as I read, most commonly by decompiling the app). I really want to avoid that!

So what do you experienced Android developers use? I know the answer seems obvious. But the reason I ask this is because I would like to avoid having my infrastructure, which I need to update etc. But to be able to register users, without the need of an third party which supports OpenID like twitter, facebook or Google, AND secure my validation rules, it seems like I have no choice. Or do I?

Comment: If you did not see this before: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iIaEMEZnYa4

Comment: I just did, they are just promoting their products... Well, maybe I haven't read the right books yet but so far I only read solutions with Parse as the back end. The problem with that is I cannot secure my own validation rules by not storing them inside the app. But I guess I just have to deploy a Heroku or Amazon server to host a RESTful node API as backend...

Comment: Just to clarify, do your want social login provider like facebook, twitter, etc. in your app or not?

Comment: No I don't. By the way, I just read some more about Google Cloud Platform, and I'm really considering to try that. Never used GCP so, new stuff, exciting! :) Just read some nice use cases about their platform and the pricing is great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are targeting multiple platforms, it's usually best to conduct the majority of your business logic in an api outside of the app.  It reduces code duplication and if validation is done at the api level, it limits the ability of malicious users to bypass validation rules.

With that said, running your own api doesn't necessarily require running your own infrastructure. Two AWS web services that could help are [Amazon API Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/) and [AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/).  Registering your users can be done using [Amazon Cognito Your User Pools](https://aws.amazon.com/cognito/).